# Redirect to a View instead of returning a Response to jQuery ajax $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect, action

I'm trying to validate a form using jQuery and submitting it after successful validation.

My controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Calculator(FormCollection data)
{
    var report = ; // getting it from database
    return RedirectToAction("Report", report);
}
```

And my jQuery ajax call looks like this:

```
$("#btnCalculateScore").click(function (e) {
   if (validateData()) {
      var $frm = $("#frmCalculator");
      var url = $frm.prop("action");
      $.post(url, $frm.serialize(), function (data) {
                //do something with response from server
      });
   }
});
```

Since, I am using a jQuery ajax call here, my controller post method returning a response back to my ajax call instead of redirecting to Report View().

How can I redirect to Report View with data after ajax post call? please help me in this.

Comment: You should create a url and redirect the user to that url.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you can't just use an actionlink for this?

Comment: The whole point of using ajax is to stay on the **same** page - if you want to redirect then do not use ajax

Comment: @PeterSmith Got it! Thanks.